# Text-Galaga: Continuous Text-Game Looping and Controlling Character

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, loops, text

just for fun and possibly for a project for my computer science class, I was making a text based "Galaga" game. Your character is ">" and the enemies are "<" and the lasers are "~" or "-", point is, its pretty simple. 600-700 lines of code. Problem is, you have to enter something for the code to loop. I used system("stty raw") so that I don't have to press enter, but the game stops when you stop holding or pressing buttons. I want to make it a real continuous game that is just made out of text. Any way to accomplish this while also being able to control the movement of your character properly using WASD movements? I am also using Xcode on a macbook if that helps. And this is part of the main function just for some context:

```
int main()
{   
cout<<" ██████╗  █████╗ ██╗      █████╗  ██████╗  █████╗ "<<endl;
cout<<"██╔════╝ ██╔══██╗██║     ██╔══██╗██╔════╝ ██╔══██╗"<<endl;
cout<<"██║  ███╗███████║██║     ███████║██║  ███╗███████║"<<endl;
cout<<"██║   ██║██╔══██║██║     ██╔══██║██║   ██║██╔══██║"<<endl;
cout<<"╚██████╔╝██║  ██║███████╗██║  ██║╚██████╔╝██║  ██║"<<endl;
cout<<" ╚═════╝ ╚═╝  ╚═╝╚══════╝╚═╝  ╚═╝ ╚═════╝ ╚═╝  ╚═╝ "<<endl;

cout<<endl<<endl;

cout<<"Welcome to text-galaga!"<<endl;
cout<<"_________________________"<<endl;
cout<<"Use W to move forward,"<<endl;
cout<<"A to move left, S to move back,"<<endl;
cout<<"D to move right, and J to shoot"<<endl;
cout<<"_________________________"<<endl;

cout<<"Good luck!"<<endl<<endl;
cout<< "Enter any key to begin..."<<endl;
cin>>x;

// Set terminal to raw mode
system("stty raw");

char input ='c';
int height=10,wide=5;
int turns=0;
int num_destroyed=0;

// ACTUAL MAIN GAME OPERATIONS START HERE...

while((input!='Q'&& input!='q') && (num_destroyed<5) && dead==false)
{
    // Wait for single character
    input = getchar();
    int i=0;
    int j=0;

    get_inputs(i, j, bad);

    render(i, j, height, wide, input, destroyed, dead, bad, turns, shot,
           constant_height, constant_wide, shot_distance, next, num_destroyed);

    draw(height, wide, j, i, destroyed, dead, bad, shot_distance, shot,
         constant_height, constant_wide);

    if ((num_destroyed<5) && dead==false)
        cout<<endl<<endl;
    ++turns;
}

// Reset terminal to normal "cooked" mode
system("stty cooked");

// Game End Information
if (num_destroyed==5)
{
    cout<<"Congradulations! You win!"<<endl<<endl;
}
if (dead==true)
{
    cout<<"You died. Game Over."<<endl<<endl;
}
cout<<"Frames used: "<<turns<<endl;

return 0;
// AND END HERE...
}
```

Anyways, I know that I should probably put "while (true)" and take out the "getchar()" once I have the rest figured out, but that alone doesn't seem to make it into a sufficient game like a text-galaga. Anyways, sorry about the long post. Thanks guys.

Comment: I'd recommend checking out [ncurses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses). It's just what you need.

Comment: Couldn't get it to work, it would just say Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_endwin", referenced from:
      _main in main.o